# Adafruit TFT 1.3 inch display with arduino-rotate the font

Tags: display, mkr1000

I am using Arduino MKR1500 with adafruit 1.3 inch display(https://www.adafruit.com/product/4313) and I want to rotate the font on the screen by 90 degree. I tried setRotation() and added an angle in the brackets. but that did not help.

Can someone please let me know what command do I need to use to do that?

Comment: setRotation usually takes a number 0-3 for 90 degree steps

Comment: Hi Majenko, I tried setting it up to 0,1,2 in void setup() none of them changed the display setting . Is there something I could be missing?

Comment: Sorry, I figured it out. I was supposed to configure that in void tftPrintTest().